# WIFI not listed in the network list

Tags: networking, drivers, 18.04, network-manager, router

today my internet company (Portugal) changed the house router: 
*HitronTechnologies - Broadband Voice Wireless Gateway - CVE-30360 ZON*

it works just fine in all the telephones in the house and also in another laptop with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS as operation system.

Lots of networks appear on the network list of available WIFI spots, but the name of 'my' network (NOS-B5D0) just doesn't appear.

putting *lshw -C network* in a terminal gives me this:

```
 description: Wireless interface     
 product: QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter          
 vendor: Qualcomm Atheros         
 physical id: 0          
 bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0          
 logical name: wlp3s0          
 version: 31          
 serial: 3c:95:09:e8:6e:75         
 width: 64 bits          
 clock: 33MHz          
 capabilities: bus_master  
 cap_list ethernet physical wireless         
 configuration: broadcast=yes  
 driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=5.3.0-40-generic  
 firmware=WLAN.TF.2.1-00021-QCARMSWP-1 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes  
 wireless=IEEE 802.11         
 resources: irq:132 memory:b1000000-b11fffff
```

`nmcli device wifi list` shows:

```
IN-USE  SSID                MODE   CHAN  RATE        SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY        
        DIRECT-D5-HP Tango  Infra  36    65 Mbit/s   57      ▂▄▆_  WPA2      
        Luke_Skywalker      Infra  11    130 Mbit/s  25      ▂___  WPA1 WPA2 
        MEO-BORRALHO        Infra  6     130 Mbit/s  55      ▂▄__  WPA1 WPA2  
        MEO-WiFi            Infra  1     130 Mbit/s  59      ▂▄▆_  --        
        MEO-WiFi            Infra  1     195 Mbit/s  17      ▂___  --        
        MEO-WiFi            Infra  6     130 Mbit/s  55      ▂▄__  --               
        NOS_WIFI_Fon        Infra  11    130 Mbit/s  25      ▂___  --        
        NOS_WIFI_Fon        Infra  12    130 Mbit/s  44      ▂▄__  --               
        NOS_WIFI_Fon        Infra  12    130 Mbit/s  49      ▂▄__  --             
        NOS_WIFI_Fon        Infra  3     130 Mbit/s  19      ▂___  --        
        NOS_WIFI_Fon        Infra  3     130 Mbit/s  22      ▂___  --        
        NOS_WIFI_Fon        Infra  4     130 Mbit/s  24      ▂___  --        
        NOS_WIFI_Fon        Infra  5     130 Mbit/s  30      ▂___  --             
        NOS_WIFI_Fon        Infra  5     130 Mbit/s  72      ▂▄▆_  --             
        NOS_WIFI_Fon        Infra  7     130 Mbit/s  24      ▂___  --        
        NOS_WIFI_Fon        Infra  7     130 Mbit/s  40      ▂▄__  --                    
        NOS_WIFI_Fon        Infra  8     130 Mbit/s  47      ▂▄__  --        
        NOS_WIFI_Fon        Infra  9     130 Mbit/s  42      ▂▄__  --             
        NOS-1ED0            Infra  7     130 Mbit/s  25      ▂___  WPA1 WPA2   
        NOS-2962            Infra  11    195 Mbit/s  44      ▂▄__  WPA2        
        NOS-2F52            Infra  5     195 Mbit/s  17      ▂___  WPA2      
        NOS-4400            Infra  4     130 Mbit/s  25      ▂___  WPA1 WPA2 
        NOS-59F0            Infra  12    130 Mbit/s  15      ▂___  WPA1 WPA2 
        NOS-62D0            Infra  3     130 Mbit/s  24      ▂___  WPA1 WPA2 
        NOS-73A0            Infra  3     130 Mbit/s  24      ▂___  WPA1 WPA2 
        NOS-81F0            Infra  5     130 Mbit/s  75      ▂▄▆_  WPA1 WPA2 
        NOS-A700            Infra  8     130 Mbit/s  40      ▂▄__  WPA1 WPA2 
        NOS-B920            Infra  12    130 Mbit/s  44      ▂▄__  WPA1 WPA2 
        NOS-C020            Infra  9     130 Mbit/s  45      ▂▄__  WPA1 WPA2 
        NOS-FC10            Infra  12    130 Mbit/s  52      ▂▄__  WPA1 WPA2 
        Valentim WIFI       Infra  5     130 Mbit/s  29      ▂___  WPA1 WPA2 
        Xones               Infra  1     130 Mbit/s  57      ▂▄▆_  WPA1 WPA2 
        Xones 5G            Infra  56    405 Mbit/s  29      ▂___  WPA1 WPA2
```

```
nmcli device wifi list
```

on the other computer where the wifi works shows:

```
IN-USE  SSID                     MODE   CHAN  RATE        SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY  
        NOS_WIFI_Fon             Infra  13    130 Mbit/s  90      ▂▄▆█  --        
        MEO-BORRALHO             Infra  6     130 Mbit/s  80      ▂▄▆_  WPA1 WPA2
        MEO-WiFi                 Infra  6     130 Mbit/s  80      ▂▄▆_  --        
        ZON-D920                 Infra  13    130 Mbit/s  79      ▂▄▆_  WPA1 WPA2
        NOS_WIFI_Fon             Infra  13    130 Mbit/s  79      ▂▄▆_  --        
*       NOS-B5D0                 Infra  13    130 Mbit/s  71      ▂▄▆_  WPA1 WPA2
        NOS-81F0                 Infra  5     130 Mbit/s  70      ▂▄▆_  WPA1 WPA2
        MEO-WiFi                 Infra  1     130 Mbit/s  60      ▂▄▆_  --        
        Xones                    Infra  1     130 Mbit/s  59      ▂▄▆_  WPA1 WPA2
        NOS_WIFI_Fon             Infra  5     130 Mbit/s  52      ▂▄__  --        
        Audi_Potente             Infra  7     130 Mbit/s  52      ▂▄__  WPA1 WPA2
        NOS_WIFI_Fon             Infra  7     130 Mbit/s  52      ▂▄__  --        
        NOS_WIFI_Fon             Infra  12    130 Mbit/s  44      ▂▄__  --        
        NOS-B920                 Infra  12    130 Mbit/s  42      ▂▄__  WPA1 WPA2
        NOS_WIFI_Fon             Infra  12    130 Mbit/s  42      ▂▄__  --        
        NOS-2962                 Infra  11    195 Mbit/s  40      ▂▄__  WPA2      
        NOS_WIFI_Fon             Infra  9     130 Mbit/s  39      ▂▄__  --        
        NOS-FC10                 Infra  12    130 Mbit/s  37      ▂▄__  WPA1 WPA2
        NOS_WIFI_Fon             Infra  8     130 Mbit/s  35      ▂▄__  --        
        NOS-A700                 Infra  8     130 Mbit/s  34      ▂▄__  WPA1 WPA2
        NOS-2962-5               Infra  36    540 Mbit/s  34      ▂▄__  WPA2      
        DIRECT-D5-HP Tango       Infra  36    65 Mbit/s   34      ▂▄__  WPA2      
        NOS-C020                 Infra  9     130 Mbit/s  30      ▂___  WPA1 WPA2
        Xones 5G                 Infra  56    405 Mbit/s  30      ▂___  WPA1 WPA2
        NOS-15B7                 Infra  4     195 Mbit/s  27      ▂___  WPA2      
        NOS_Internet_Movel_9AD3  Infra  6     270 Mbit/s  27      ▂___  WPA1 WPA2
        NOS-4400                 Infra  4     130 Mbit/s  24      ▂___  WPA1 WPA2
```

If I connect the machine to the computer I can access the internet, but I can't manage to connect via WiFi.  How may I troubleshoot this?

Comment: Please run `nmcli device wifi list` on the other laptop with Ubuntu, click [edit], and paste its results here. Then, go to the new router and obtain its make and model, and also add that to your question. BTW, I sorted the list and removed duplicates. TY!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Router is probably using wifi channel 12-14 which is illegal in some countries. Try statically switching wifi channel on router to something in range 1-11.

Comment: thanks for your answer, how do I statically switch wifi channel on router to something in range 1-11?, Thanks again

Comment: Don't know make or model of your router. It will have a tiny web server inside which its documentation will show how to access.

Comment: I've had a same problem when I was in Portugal. Type "netstat -r" in terminal to see router ip(gateway), then login to it, you will need user and pass.

Comment: Changing the wifi channel to 1 made the the network appear in the network list. Thanks!!!